# Jquery select div element included in php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to JQuery and I may be missing a few things about it.

I have created a .php file which contains the header of my website. I included it into my main .php file. The "header.php" contains a 'div class= userbox_rectangle_full_header' that I would like to select from a JQuery loaded in the main "homepage.php".

I tried selecting it to show an alert on the click of the 'div'. When the Jquery is loaded in the "header.php", no problem, the alert correctly shows. But nothing happens when the .js file is loaded in "homepage.php".

Hope you'll be able to help me about what I'm missing.

The main homepage in which I load the JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <title>DSI Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homepage.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <?php include 'header.php';?>
        </header>

        <div class="work_space" id="homepage_work_space">HOMEPAGE</div>
        <div class="work_space" id="userpage_work_space">USERPAGE</div>
    </body>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery_color_animation.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script/homepage_script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The "header.php" file which I include into the main "homepage.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/header.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="userbox_rectangle_full_header">&nbsp</div>
        </header>
    </body>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery_color_animation.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script/header_animation.js"></script>
</html>
```

Finally, the JQuery code which is not working when loaded in the "homepage.php", but working when loaded in the "header.php":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#homepage_work_space').on('click', function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: can you show where you putted the js block in hompage.php?

Comment: one simply cannot nest a `<body>` tag inside a `<head>` tag.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for your replies, I updated with the complete version of the "homepage.php" file, this structure seems correct to me ? I have the same structure for the "header.php" as well.

Comment: any errors in browser's console??

Comment: No errors in browser, just a JQuery alert not showing up :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some points in your code thats better to know .

1. Your html structure is wrong! simple html5 structure:

   `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Title of the document</title>
   <!-- Your JQuery Main File -->
   </head>
   <body>
   Content of the document......
   </body>
   </html>`
2. Define your main jquery file in head of your body.
3. Your document has 2 `<body>` tag . (one your main body and other included from header.php )
4. Define your script files(except jquery that defined in head) in the footer , just before `</body>`
5. And in your header.php file dont define any script!
   Have a good time!

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad GH ! But how can I do to have only 1 <body> tag if I include one php file into another ?

Comment: youre welcome @Yvesmarie ! just you remove the <body> and </body> from your header.php file!your header.php file must be just :<div class="userbox_rectangle_full_header">&nbsp</div>

Comment: PHP include just copy your header.php content  and paste them in the place that included!(<header>in your code)

Comment: Finally, it worked by removing the <body> tag as you said in your two last comments ! Thanks a lot @Mohammad GH

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading in the scripts outside of the body. Make sure to load them inside your `<head>` tags.

Comment: loading them inside the `<body>` tag might also work (such "footer scripts" are actually quite common, in order to have the markup being rendered, before scripts are being evaluated); but not outside of either tags.

Comment: Right, putting them in `<body>` is fine, but OP already had their code in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However, neither of your methods actually works, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Yvesmarie Post your full homepage.php file and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

here's a copy and paste from the revision history of the question, in order to demonstrate how the `HTML` markup should look alike, according to the op's description ...

file `index.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery_color_animation.js"/>
        <script src="../js/script/homepage_script.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

        <!-- further content goes here -->

    </body>
</html>
```

file `header.php`:

```
<div class="userbox_rectangle_full_header">
    <div class="work_space" id="homepage_work_space">HOMEPAGE</div>
    <div class="work_space" id="userpage_work_space">USERPAGE</div>
</div>
```

file `homepage_script.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.work_space').on('click', function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

I'd suggest [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com) or any other PHP template-engine, which are frameworks specialized on rendering HTML markup, including template bits, etc.

Comment: ok, i'll check Twig. But I'll be surprise that there isn't a simpler answer, requesting no additionnal frameworks :)

Comment: @Yvesmarie this is the most minimal answer possible; while Twig is just a suggestion, how this is commonly done, when producing more complex templates - and it is way simpler than writing a custom template engine (it's `include` & `require_once` vs. just inserting a template tag there)... nevertheless it's helpful, to understand how it is done in bare PHP, without any framework. jQuery is also abstracting the bare JavaScript.